# Issue of re-rendering the component on url change

Tags: reactjs, render, react-router-dom

I'm new to react and I have some trouble re-rendering a component when I do my assignment.

On my navbar I have three links: `Home, user and Courses.`

If an user clicks on the "courses" (/courses?quick-courses=true#courses), the component will render and display the list of courses(the Links). If the user clicks on one of the Links such as "The Javascript"(/courses/3?title= Javascript) and then click the "Courses"  (/courses?quick-courses=true#courses) from the navbar again,  the content from the "courses" component will not be render again to display the list of course content.

I tried to use the shouldComponentUpdate() and componentDidUpdate() to assign the this.props.location.search to the state and many other ways to solve this issue. however it doesn't work for me.

Here's my components and what I did so far :[components-assignment-3](https://gist.github.com/simidaspam/6599f4419b35d373bc0b2e8954dbf7d6)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you click `/courses?quick-courses=true#courses` you render this route `<Route path="/courses" component={Courses} />`

at this point, that route is loaded and mounted

then you click `/courses/3?title= Javascript` and you render `<Route path={"/courses/:id"} exact component={Course} />`

now clicking on `/courses?quick-courses=true#courses` won't re-render `<Route path="/courses" component={Courses} />` **again** as it's already rendered, you're already inside of this route. that's why none of you lifecycle hooks will fire **again** and your `showCourse` will be `false` so that's why you won't see `headerCheck`

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Is there any way I can fix this? I tried to reset the state in shouldComponentUpdate() and componentDidUpdate(), but it didn't work for me. Can you please let me know how to overcome this issue? Thank you.

Comment: make your `/courses` accept the course ID like so `<Route path="/courses/:id?" component={Courses} />` .

remove `<Route path={"/courses/:id"} exact component={Course} />` and make `Course` component accept ID from parent `Courses` route

and for the last part in your `Courses` route check if there's `this.props.match.params.id`, if it is show `Course` and hide header.